# Normalised Basis for vector space V.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let 
$$
V= \{ (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})' \in \mathbb{R}^{3} | \, 3 x_{1} + x_{2} = 0 \text{ and } 2 x_{1} - x_{3} = 0\} $$

What is the normalised basis for V?

I tried it two different ways:

$x_{2} = -3 x_{1}$ and $x_{3} = 2 x_{1}$

Hence, basis is: $\{ (1, -3, 0)' ; (1,0,2)' \}$

Or, do I take a combination like:
Basis: $\{ (1,-3,2) \}$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is "*the* normalized" basis of a vector space?

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe it means the normed basis? $||x|| = 1$?

Comment: Then you mean "orthonormal" basis. Have you studied already the Gram-Schmidt process to orthonormalize vectors? And what inner product do you have here? The usual one?

Comment: Why you have four components $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @DonAntonio I am aware of GS orthonormalisation, but I am having trouble getting the basis to input into the process. The inner product is Euclidean.

Comment: @Emilio Novati terrible mistake by me. Thank you. That did not make sense for the question.

Comment: Besides the above correction, observe that $\;\dim V=1\;$ , not $\;2\;$ as apparently tou considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basis for $\;V\;$ is, for example

$$x_2=-3x_1\;,\;\;x_3=2x_1\implies\left\{\;v:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\!-3\\2\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

and thus an orthonormalized basis here is pretty boring: just multiply $\;v\;$ by $\;\frac1{\left\|v\right\|}\;$ :

$$u:=\frac v{\left\|v\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt{14}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\\!-3\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt{14}}\\\!-\frac3{\sqrt{14}}\\\frac2{\sqrt{14}}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you. I am still having trouble with understanding how to determine dimensions based on different linear combinations. For example the next question is a basis for $\mathbb {R}^{4}$ with $x_{2} - 2x_{4}=0$ and $2x_{1} + 3x_{3}=0$. Is $\dim(V) =1$ still?

Comment: @A.T Check *the freedom variables*, meaning: after you determine the conditions, how many variables can be chosen *freely*? In your first example observe that $\;x_1\;$ can be chosen freely, but after that you **have no choice** for neither $\;x_2\;$ nor $\;x_3\;$ , and thus the dimension is $\;1\;$ . In your example in your last comment, you can freely choose $\;x_3,x_4\;$ (they are not "connected" or "related" by some equation or condition), and then $\;x_1,x_2\;$ are completely and uniquely determined, so here the dimension is $\;2\;$ .

Comment: hence the basis (not normalised) is $\{ (1, 0, - \frac {2}{3}, 0); (0,1,0, \frac{1}{2}) \}$ ?

Comment: @A.T Yes, indeed. In this case is even easier than in the usual: you don't *have* to orthogonalize that basis as it already is orthogonal! You only have to normalize each vector.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the continuous questions, but suppose a basis for $\mathbb {R}^{3}$ with $2x_{1} - x_{2} +5 x_{3}=0$. Then $\dim{V} =2$ and a spanning set would be $\{(1,2,0)',(0,5,1)'\}$. But they are not orthogonal, so do I use GS orthogonalisation? Would I get a basis through that way?

Comment: Edit: that was not smart, a basis does not have to be orthogonal, excuse me. Hence, that is by normalising the above, I get my normalised basis. Thanks for the help.